# How to set environment variable in Boost Build for Boost Unit Test Framework?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, boost-unit-test-framework

Please note that:

- I am using Boost Build and Boost Unit Test Framework. This means when I build a test it is automatically run it and show the result.
- For *running* the GCC variant (and not the compile-time nor clang), I need to set the environment variable `LC_ALL` to `C`.

How do I do this in my Jamfile?

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.builtins.testing) an option called `testing.arg`, you can use it to send arguments to the UnitTest's executable before starting it.

[Here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config.html) you can find information that you can set the environment variable using the following syntax in the UnitTest's command line `--<command_line_argument_name>=<argument_value>`.

By combining both information, we can assume that this will help you:

```
unit-test helpers_test
    : helpers_test.cpp helpers
    : <testing.arg>"--LC_ALL=C"
;
``
```

Comment: I don't think `testing.arg` or `--<command_line_argument_name>=<argument_value>` have anything to do with environment variables. Using `<testing.arg>"--LC_ALL=C"` gave me message `An unrecognized parameter in the argument LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: Haven't tested but maybe `<testing.launcher>` option with the `env` linux program might give you what you need to unix/osx variants. The option `<testing.launcher>env KEY=VALUE` would expand to `env KEY=VALUE your_program`